# Replace Quote with Escape and Quote

Tags: c#

Dumb question probably, but can't seem to get it to work. I need to Replace quotes from a textbox with \" so it will export to excel correctly. I'm trying:

```
[Note].Text).Replace("\"", "\"")
```

Am I doing it completely wrong? Wouldn't surprise me if I am. Any recommendations on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `...Replace("\"", "\\\"")` (gotta escape the backslash and quote in replacement)

Comment: Are you sure Excel needs `\"` ? I would expect that no escaping is needed. Concrete example?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
String quotedText = "\"Hello, world!\"";
// quotedText = "Hello, World!"
String newQuotedText = quotedText.replace("\"", "\\\"");
// newQuotedText = \"Hello, World!\"
```

You need to escape the backslash you want transferred to the new value as well.

Answer (score 2):

`.Replace("\"", "\\\"")`

`\\` means `\` character. You must escape it too, so it can be shown.

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the backslash as well as the quote:

```
mystring.Replace("\"", "\\\"")
```

Comment: I was trying to do exactly the opposite replace and was getting cross-eyed over it. Thanks for clarifying it for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

You need 3 \ for the replacement string, the first one to escape the second one so that a \ will appear in the value, and the third one to escape the quotes

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
string s = "diana\"s here";
string s2=s.Replace ("\"","\\\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy, but i'm almost sure it works.

```
Replace("\"","\\" + "\"");
```